# What causes page fault and how to minimize them?

Tags: optimization, memory-management

When examining a process in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), what does it mean when there are several page faults?  The application is processing quite a bit of data and the UI is not very responsive.  Are there optimizations to the code that could reduce or eliminate page faults?  Would increasing the physical RAM of the system make a difference?

Comment: Just a thought, with linux, we can use `mloc` to get the entire physical address before hand to avoid page faults walk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault

Increasing the physical RAM on your machine could result in fewer page faults, although design changes to your application will do much better than adding RAM.  In general, having a smaller memory footprint, and having things that will often be accessed around the same time be on the same page will decrease the number of page faults.  It can, also, be helpful to try to do everything you can with some bit of data in memory all at once so that you don't need to access it many different times, which may cause page faults (aka thrashing).

Answer (score 3):

It might also be helpful to make sure that memory that is accessed after each other is near to each other (eg if you have some objects, place them in an array) if these objects have lots of data that is very infrequently used, place it in another class and make the first class have a reference to the second one. This way you will use less memory most of the time.

Comment: +1: While this is a pattern I was well-aware of in database design, I had never really considered it for OO-design.  I like it!

Answer (score 0):

A design option would be to write a memory cache system, lazy creating memory (create on demand). such cache would have a collection of pre-allocated memory chunks, accessed by their size. For example, an array of N lists, each list having M buffers.each list is responsible to bring you memory in a certain size range. (for example, from  each list bringing you memory in the range of 2^i (i = 0..N-1). even if you want to use less then 2^i, you just dont use the extra memory in the buffer.
this would be a tradeoff of small memory waste, vs caching and less page faults.

another option is to use [nedmalloc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nedmalloc/)

good luck
Lior